# Problem with PHP printing in drop down box

Tags: php

I have a mysql query:

`$ziua = "SELECT DISTINCT DAYOFMONTH(ziua) FROM rapoarte";
$ziuaResult = mysql_query($ziua);`

With the results i get, i want to add them in a drop down box, like this:
`
            echo"Selectati Ziua:

```
            <td><select name='ziua'>
            <option value='---'>---</option>";
        while($ziuaRow = mysql_fetch_array($ziuaResult)) {
         $ziua1 = $ziuaRow['ziua'];
         echo "<option value='$ziua1'>$ziua1</option>";
        }
```

echo"";

`

the problem is that my drop-down boxes are empty. there are 2, 3 options (depending on the select result), but no text is shown.

I have the same problem with this selection:
`SELECT DISTINCT HOUR(ora) FROM rapoarte`

How can i fix this?

thanks,
Sebastian

**EDIT**

sorry, 
i added the wrong code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only selecting `HOUR(ora)` without the column  `ziua`.
The following should select the `ziua` column, unique by `HOUR(ora)`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT HOUR(ora) AS something,ziua FROM rapoarte GROUP by something
```

If you turned `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on, you would see an error about an undefined index, `ziua`.

Comment: where do you see this 'linie'

Comment: In his previous question. Updated the answer as the code from his question has changed too.

Answer (score 0):

Should your argument passed to mysql_fetch_array() be `$ziuaResult` instead of `$trunchiResult` ?

Comment: I agree with Lekensteyn's answer too.

Answer (score -1):

this should work:

```
echo "<option value='".$trunchi1."'>".$trunchi1."</option>";
```

Comment: Not really, this is just another approach to insert `$trunchi1` into the string.