# SQL query won't populate my drop-down box

Tags: php

I have a problem with this query and drop down box:

```
$ziua = "SELECT DISTINCT DAYOFMONTH(ziua) FROM rapoarte"; 

$ziuaResult = mysql_query($ziua);
```

Populating the drop down box :

```
echo"<td>Selectati Ziua:</td>    
<td><select name='ziua'>     
<option value='---'>---</option>";

while($ziuaRow = mysql_fetch_array($ziuaResult)) 
{    
    $ziua1 = $ziuaRow['ziua'];     
    echo "<option value='$ziua1'>$ziua1</option>";
}
```

For an reason unknown to me, the drop down box is populated, but no values are shown. (there are  2-3 empty options)

Comment: Link to same part one of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088045/problem-with-php-printing-in-drop-down-box/4088108#4088108

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because there is no such column `ziua` in your query. Use alias in the query `SELECT DISTINCT DAYOFMONTH(ziua) as dm FROM rapoarte` and then `$ziua1 = $ziuaRow['dm'];` or access result by integer index `$ziua1 = $ziuaRow[0];`

Comment: the query works fine. i've tested it in mysql and had no problems. i have a column named `ziua`.

Comment: But your query has `DISTINCT DAYOFMONTH(ziua) `, not `ziua`. So in result set this column doesn't appear as `ziua`, but as something like `[DISTINCT DAYOFMONTH(ziua)]`. So you cannot access it using name `ziua`

Comment: Use alias or access it by int index.

Comment: thaks, that sloved it! the correct way is `$_POST['DAYOFMONTH(ziua)']`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the field name is not correct. I have tried that as well. It will give you the reult.